# Can I use google app engine to work as a WMS or some sort of geoserver that I can use to connect openlayers?

Tags: google, server

Has anybody ever heard or tried doing anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHPGeoTiles (both for Local Storage and Google App Engine - GAE)**

PHPGeoTiles is storing map tiles on your disk or **Google App Engine's database**, "BigTable". The difference of PHPGeoTiles is using Google App Engine to store tiles addition to disk storage.

http://www.geowebdeveloper.com/tag/google-app-engine/

http://www.geowebdeveloper.com/phpgeotiles/

Answer (score 1):

gae-wms is a Web Map Service implementation for raster imagery, including a tile cache, for running on Google App Engine.

http://code.google.com/p/gae-wms/